# Java - Hex String representation to integer Hex

Tags: java, formatting, hex

I have a string as "5F2A" as Hex. I would like to convert it as int 0x5F2A.

```
String str = "5F2A";
int number = someOperation(str);
```

And the number should be (with 0x)

> 0x5F2A

Is it possible?

**To rephrase and share what I learnt today**

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(0x5F2A, "somevalue");

System.out.println(map.get(24362));
System.out.println(map.get(0b0101111100101010));
```

Would give the value `somevalue` for both.

Comment: No, that's not possible. `System.out.println(number);` will always output in decimal, not hexadecimal. You can use `System.out.format`.

Comment: I do not want to print it. I want to use it as Integer. e.g `int i = 0x5F2A;`

Comment: `int number = Integer.parseInt(str, 16);` is transforming a `String` to an `int` with base 16(hex).

Comment: @AshutoshVaidya Then you should update your question, because right now it states that the code you posted should show the output `0x5F2A`.

Comment: Thank you @ErwinBolwidt I was not aware numbers could be used interchangeably.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No transformation required:

```
System.out.println("0x" + str);
```

And to turn an arbitrary int into HEX representation:

```
Integer.toHexString(intNumber);
```

That should be all you need to get going!

Comment: It is still the string. I want integer.

Comment: @AshutoshVaidya You can do the conversion to Integer through [`Integer.parseInt(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)).

Comment: It would give me a decimal number as 24362. I need as `int n = 0x5F2A;`

Comment: @AshutoshVaidya You are confusing storing the variable vs printing the variable

Comment: @AshutoshVaidya `0x5F2A` is only a represenation of number `24362`. And this is only a presentation for binary `101111100101010`.

Comment: @Flown Thank you for clarifying. I was not aware if it could be used interchangeably. I just tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

`int i = 0x5F2A` not really means nothing because in memory, all is in binary, it's only when you print that it matters

```
String str = "5F2A";
int number = Integer.parseInt(str, 16); //alows to store an int, binary 0101111100101010

System.out.println(number);                      //24362 (decimal by default)
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(number)); //5f2a  (hexa possible too)
```

By default, it prints in (binary into) decimal format, but you can print in hexa format, but `int i = 0x5F2A` means at **100% the same** as `int i = 24362`

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware numbers could be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int))

```
Integer.parseInt(/*your String*/, 16);
```

16 is the radix for hexadecimal.